# Missing DLLs cross-compile wxWidgets shared library on ubuntu

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

I try to cross-compile under Linux to Windows using the shared library.
I followed the instructions on wxWidgets wiki but while executing main out.exe I got a lot of missing DLL Errors.

Here's how I builded the library :

```
../configure --disable-debug_flag --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu -with-msw
```

Here's how I compile and Link :

```
First : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -c  *.cpp  *.h  $(/wxWidgets/build_win/wx-config --cxxflags)

Second : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o out.exe *.o  $(/wxWidgets/build_win/wx-config --libs) -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

When I use wine out.exe I got these errors :

```
002a:err:module:import_dll Library wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\test.exe") not found
002a:err:module:import_dll Library wxmsw313u_core_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\test.exe") not found
002a:err:module:attach_dlls Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\test.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

I've added the missing DLLs in the same folder as out.exe (They were located in /wxWidgets/build_win/lib/ ) and doing this added lot of more errors :

```
wine out.exe 
0028:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\out.exe") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\wxmsw313u_core_gcc_custom.dll") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\wxmsw313u_core_gcc_custom.dll") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\wxmsw313u_core_gcc_custom.dll") not found
0028:err:module:import_dll Library wxmsw313u_core_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\out.exe") not found
0028:err:module:attach_dlls Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\ubuntu\\Bureau\\test\\out.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Here's my folder content :

```
ChildPanels.o                  wxmsw313u_gl_gcc_custom.dll
main.o                         wxmsw313u_html_gcc_custom.dll
MainPanel.o                    wxmsw313u_media_gcc_custom.dll
out.exe                        wxmsw313u_propgrid_gcc_custom.dll
wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll      wxmsw313u_qa_gcc_custom.dll
wxbase313u_net_gcc_custom.dll  wxmsw313u_ribbon_gcc_custom.dll
wxbase313u_xml_gcc_custom.dll  wxmsw313u_richtext_gcc_custom.dll
wxmsw313u_adv_gcc_custom.dll   wxmsw313u_stc_gcc_custom.dll
wxmsw313u_aui_gcc_custom.dll   wxmsw313u_webview_gcc_custom.dll
wxmsw313u_core_gcc_custom.dll  wxmsw313u_xrc_gcc_custom.dll
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

**EDIT :**

It work copying all of these DLLs to my folder :

```
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll  libstdc++-6.dll  libwinpthread-1.dll wxmsw313u_core_gcc_custom.dll  wxbase313u_gcc_custom.dll
```

I don't understand why I need to copy the libgcc and libstdc++ to my folder because I linked them staticly. Is it not possible to link static libgcc and libstdc++ and shared wxWidgets ?

Also, how can I tell the compiler I want my DLLs to be loaded from a folder named /lib for example inside my app folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really wxWidgets-specific, but just the way that DLLs work: they need to be found during the program execution and this means either being in the same directory as the program itself, or in one of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable.

You can't "tell the compiler" anything about the path where the DLLs are found because this path must be used at *run* time, not *compile* time.

The simplest workaround if you really, really want to have the DLLs in another directory is to use a wrapper (it could be a script or another compiled program) that would add this directory to the `PATH` before launching the real application. Alternatively, just link statically and don't bother with the DLLs at all.

Comment: Hi @VZ.
Thanks for the explanations I understand more what I should do now.
However I don't understand why I need to put the libgcc and libstdc++ DLLS in the same folder because I linked them staticly at compilation using -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

Comment: To not have dependencies on the compiler run-time DLLs you need to link wx DLLs using the same options you used to link them statically in your own application.